# vCenter 6.5 how to add a serial port?

Tags: vmware-vcenter

in vCenter 6.5 web client, I don't see a way to add a serial port to a new or existing VM. When I edit VM settings, the only options under Add New Hardware are hard drives, CD/DVD, Network adapters or SCSI controllers.

Is this a limitation of my edition of vCenter? I'm using essentials right now. vCenter clearly knows about the serial port (if I add it using the vSphere client directly against the host) and it can even prompt me to answer the question of whether the serial port's log should go to a file via append/replace. But I can't add a new port, change where the file is going, etc.

Comment: Make sure the VM is turned off when you try to add the hardware.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that doesn't seem to make a difference for me. While in the overview of the VM settings, I see the serial port, when I edit settings, the serial port simply isn't there and it doesn't appear in the Add New Device dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the VMWare doc that applies to vCenter 6.5.  And as Gerald mentioned, you probably also need the VM shut down to make changes.

Accessing the page with IE and flash will provide more options.
I've seen several options that aren't available unless you are running Flash.
This might be one of them.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-941460CF-7C1E-45F7-B964-E16189183768.html

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what it turned out to be, I was using the HTML5 UI which has quite limited functionality.